# bootstrap: how do I use a progress bar in a row-fluid div?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap, I want to put a button next to a progress-bar in a a row-fluid div. I cannot figure out why it doesn't work. Here is my code. Any thought?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">button</div>
        <div class="span10 progress">
            <div class="bar bar-info" style="width: 50%;">
                bar10
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What specifically about it doesn't work?

Comment: The span10 progress div resizes in a manner which destroys the look of the progress bar. Specifically it gets both wider and longer while the "bar bar-info" div holds its shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your progress div in a span10 div like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">button</div>
    <div class="span10">
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="bar bar-info" style="width: 50%;">
                bar10
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```